# SELECT a from table WHERE b = c

Tags: php, mysql

```
$video = mysql_query("SELECT vid FROM fav WHERE uid = ". $loggedInUser->user_id ."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = ". $video .""); 
if (!$result)
die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result));
echo ",$row->ID,";
```

> mySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I think the code speaks for itself, but I don´t get it, how to solve this. What did I do wrong? I only want to get the video id (vid) where the user id (uid) equals $loggedInUser->user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rec    = mysqli_query("SELECT vid FROM fav WHERE uid = ". $loggedInUser->user_id);  
$video  =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($rec);       
$id =   $video['vid'];      
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = $id");
```

EDITS

```
$records    =   array();
$rec    = mysqli_query("SELECT vid FROM fav WHERE uid = ". $loggedInUser->user_id);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rec)){
    $id =   $row['vid'];      
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = $id");  
    $records[]  =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($records);
```

Comment: +1 since this is what OP asked for

Comment: thanks a lot, but how do I fetch the rows from vid when it is not just one result, but multiple? so vid is not just one id, but several different id´s.

Comment: use a loop to get ids one by one

Comment: I added my $db to the query and it´s working just fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT tab.* FROM tab JOIN fav ON tab.ID = fav.vid AND fav.uid = ###
```

This way you won't need to execute two queries in order to get the same result. In case you need some values from `fav` too, you can add them to the `SELECT` just like `tab.*` (selects every column from `tab`).

Comment: Please correct your answer. `JOIN ... ON`, not `WHERE`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CORRUPT: Sorry, my mistake! You're absolutely right. Raheel already beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` doesn't return a string. It returns a resource.

Check the [PHP-MySQL doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to see how to retrieve data from a query result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your result using `mysql_fetch_array()` here and then assign its value

```
$arr= '';
$video = mysql_query("SELECT vid FROM fav WHERE uid = ". $loggedInUser->user_id ."");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($video)) {
    $arr = $row['vid'];
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = ". $arr ."");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getQueryData($sQuery)
{
    $result = mysql_query($sQuery); 
    $rows = Array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
       $rows[] = $row;
    }
    @mysql_free_result($result);    
    return $rows;
}
$video = getQueryData("SELECT vid FROM fav WHERE uid = ". $loggedInUser->user_id ."");
if(!empty($video)) {
   $result = getQueryData("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = ". $video[0]['vid'] .""); 
   print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only answer I can give is RTM :) But I'll explain it to you:

The method mysql_query() returns a resource. A resource is not a string, integer or array. But you can get all data you want from the resource. For example you can get the count of rows (mysql_num_rows()) or the data, selected by the query (mysql_fetch_assoc() returns it as associative array).

For more info, please take a look at the examples provided at the php-manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

**But please** use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. I'm here just talking about the functions you use in PHP. The PHP-extension mysql is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and you shouldn't use something, you now know of, will be removed. If you ask, why it is deprecated: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated